# K6 Memory Consumption per VU

Tags: load-testing, k6

I have recently started to work with k6 and really liked the approach of writing tests. When I started my first serious test I found that the memory consumption per VU is pretty high even though my test was not huge. As I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54204227/how-much-memory-for-k6-vu-virtual-user) memory consumption should be around 1-2 MB per VU if the scripts are small. In my case the memory consumption is around 5 MB per VU.

To verify how much memory a very simple script needs I created a script that is doing nothing:

```
export default function() {

}
```

When I run this script with 2000 users

`docker run --rm -v /tmp:/tmp loadimpact/k6 run -u 2000 --paused --no-teardown --no-setup /tmp/MemTest.js`

I end up with memory usage of 10 GB (about 5MB per VU)

So even if the JS is empty the memory usage is quite high. Is this expected?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you are right, it seems like either the memory usage has grown, or our previous measurements were incorrect. A brief investigation revealed that the chief culprit of the current memory usage was our use of the core.js library. I've created a new github issue to further investigate how we can improve or ameliorate the situation: https://github.com/loadimpact/k6/issues/1036

@user1171006, try using the `loadimpact/k6:master` docker image, VU memory usage should have been almost halved after we merged https://github.com/loadimpact/k6/pull/1038. That 2000 VU test you tried is taking just under 5GB of RAM on my machine now.